# An equivalent code in R for a "by" statement in SAS, to run multiple ANOVA on different levels of a variable

Tags: r, sas

I would like to run an linear model of the total catch of each species by Location. 
The data look like this:

```
Location REP TRAP SpeciesID Total
A1 A1_1 A1_1_1 Calaingr 5.288462
A1 A1_1 A1_1_1 Carataed 1.057692
A1 A1_1 A1_1_1 Harpfulv 1.057692
…
```

The model is a very simple model:
C_AOV <- lmer(Total~Location + (1|REP)). So I am considering the Location to be a fixed effect and the Rep’s to be the random effect.

In SAS, I could a use a “by” statement (by SpeciesID), which would tell SAS to run the model for each level of SpeciesID, therefore outputting 54 separate ANOVA’s, one for each species.
Is there an equivalent way to do this in R? I tried looking online, but I didn’t come across a method that I could understand. I did see plyr package and some examples but do not understand what they do.
Thanks,
sb

Answer (score 0):

I can speak for R which is going to be a little more verbose than the by statement in SAS procedures. Generally, the paradigm is split, apply, combine. You will have at least the following two options. Lets assume you have your data stored as the df object. I didn't actually run any of this code.

## Tidyverse and Broom

This won't be as intuitive with the '%>%' pipe operators and the tidyverse lingo. However, it is likely one of the more concise ways in which to do this.

```
# Not run    
library(tidyverse)

library(broom)

models <- df %>% 
 nest(-SpeciesID) %>% 
 mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lmer(Total~Location + (1|REP), data = .),
        results = map(fit, glance))%>%
 unnest(results)

models %>% select(-fit, -data)
```

## Split, Apply, Combine in a loop

IMHO, the looping construct makes this easier to understand.

```
#Not run    
split <- split(df, SpeciesID)

models <- list()

for (i in 1:length(split)) {
 model_df <- split[[i]]
 models[[i]] <-  lmer(Total~Location + (1|REP), data=model_df)
}

sapply(1:length(models), function(x) {summary(models[[x]]})
```

## The base R apply method

This method is quite concise and again highlights how the lmer function is 'applied' over various subsets of the data. The function(x) is an anonymous function where x is s sort of iterator across the levels of df$SpeciesID.

```
by(df,df$SpeciesID, function(x) summary(lmer(Total~Location + (1|REP),data = x)))
```

*Solution from comment by [Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380272/onyambu)

I'm sure there are other alternatives, but I hope this helps. As someone who transitioned from mainly SAS to mainly R this is no doubt one of things SAS makes easy; R modeling functions rarely have parameter analogous to the SAS by clause.

Comment: `by(df,df$SpeciesID, function(x) summary(lmer(Total~Location + (1|REP),data = x)))` in base R

Comment: Base R for the win...! A one-liner no less.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for your comments, I really appreciate the help. Its funny, I learned SAS in grad school (a very long time ago) and am reasonably proficient. However, due to budgetary restraints we are strongly encouraged to learn R. For some analyses, such as Species Community Analyses, spatial analyses, etc I really like the R platform and the packages submitted by others in the field. What I find somewhat difficult in R are the data transformation syntax and the parametric statistics...I guess I am so used to SAS that I get lost in it a bit. Thanks again, will try soon,

Comment: Great. I also learned SAS in school (econometrics) and after getting to know R I would much prefer it for data wrangling except for very large datasets which SAS is more capable. Please consider marking the answer as correct.